# Construct a MySQL update query in Python that only puts quotes around strings not numbers

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'd like to build an update query from a list of keys and values, only putting quotes around the values where necessary. Right now (with the below code) quotes appear around both strings and ints. How can I do this efficiently?

```
attributes = ['filename','filesize']
media_id = 12345
sqlbase = """UPDATE media
             SET %s
             WHERE media_id = %s"""
setpieces = []
values = []

setpieces.append("""timestamp_modified = %s""" % (time.time()))

#Recurse through all attributes in the class
for key in attributes:
  #For each key, get the value
  if key in attributes:
    value = getattr(self, key, None)
    setpieces.append("""%s = '%s'""" % (key, value))

query = sqlbase % (', '.join(setpieces), media_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `MySQLdb` decide that by passing *query parameters* to `execute()`:

```
sqlbase = """UPDATE media
             SET {query}
             WHERE media_id = %(media_id)s"""

mapping = {key: getattr(self, key, None) for key in ['filename', 'filesize']}
mapping['media_id'] = 12345
setpieces = ["{key} = %({key})s".format(key=key) for key in mapping] + \
            ["timestamp_modified = %s" % time.time()]

cursor.execute(sqlbase.format(query=','.join(setpieces)), mapping)
```

As a bonus, you get escaping that would help preventing SQL injections.

Also, just a side note. As you see, manually constructing a query like this doesn't look that readable and is really fragile. This is where switching to `ORM` may decrease the amount of headaches and suprises, take a look, for example: [`Pony ORM`](http://ponyorm.com/), or [`sqlalchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Comment: thank you. i'm using mysql.connector instead of mysqldb for connection pooling. is there a way to do this kind of parameterized query with mysql.connector?

Comment: @ensnare oops, seen `mysql-python` and decided it is `MySQLdb`. Though, the syntax should be [the same](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).

Comment: no worries. mysql connector has trouble parametrizing queries with dicts. how can i parameterize this myself and pass a single final query to mysql?

Comment: @ensnare hm, what kind of troubles? Should work, according to docs..the whole point of the answer is to do this with the help of the mysql python client itself since it "knows" whether it needs to put quotes or not, depending on the data type..

Comment: mysqlconnector can't parameterize mappings

Comment: See the comment here for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: @ensnare yup, but you have a single placeholder for every value, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I do. When I tried the above code it doesn't seem to parameterize properly.